# Need current login name in table automatically when value is inserted in table

Tags: sql-server

I Need the Current SQL Server Login name in the table 
when ever there is any value add to that table

Is there any way ?

Comment: This can be achieved via `AFTER  TRIGGER` for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and `SYSTEM_USER` variable

Comment: Can you please provide me any example with a Trigger

Comment: Or you could just set the `DEFAULT` value of your column to `SYSTEM_USER` (if this is only relevant to `INSERT`), and not provide the column in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: If only INSERTs to be tracked, then Larnu's tip is a good and faster alternative

Comment: Thank you it worked  Alexander and Larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `CURRENT_USER`
SQL Server function.

look at the below tutorial for more details 
[SQL Server CURRENT_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)